# Could not resolve com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev82-1.23.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gmail-api

I trey to go through the [Android Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) tutorial but these line in gradle.app file:

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev82-1.23.0'
```

give me the following error message after sync:

```
Could not resolve com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0.
Could not resolve com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev82-1.23.0.       
Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1.
```

The project compiled SDK version: API 26: Android 8.0 (Oreo)

I don't understand how to resolve these dependencies.
Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Did you check the setup dependencies in [Set Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)? It shows the supported versions.